# Custom Post Type Archive Pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, archives

I've set up a template called archive-gallery.php, and I have pagination working, however, the query is ignoring my `posts_per_page` value and using the value that is in `Settings > Reading` called `Blog Pages Show At Most`. My gallery archive page is showing 8 posts per page, which I set, and I have 48 posts in the post type. This should give me 6 pages. Wordpress is only giving me 5 pages in the pagination using `next_posts_link` with `$gallery_page_query->max_num_pages`included in the next posts link. When I go to the 6th page, which there is a link to in the pagination, I get a 404.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery Archive
*/
get_header(); ?>
  <div class="main" role="main">
    <div class="standard-section">
      <div class="gallery">
        <h1 class="big-centered-h1">
          Check out our latest work!
        </h1>
        <div class="gallery-images">
          <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $gallery_page_args = array(
              'post_type' => 'gallery',
              'posts_per_page' => 8,
              'paged' => $paged,
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'orderby' => 'date'
            );
            $gallery_page_query = new WP_Query($gallery_page_args);
            if ($gallery_page_query->have_posts()) :
              while ($gallery_page_query->have_posts()) : $gallery_page_query->the_post();
                echo '<a class="img-gallery-wrapper" href="';
                echo get_permalink($post->ID);
                echo '">';
                echo '<img class="gallery-image" src="';
                $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
                echo $featured_image_url;
                echo '">';
                echo '</a>';
              endwhile;
              wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
          ?>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-pagination">
          <?php previous_posts_link('&lt;&lt; Go back'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="right-pagination">
          <?php next_posts_link('See More &gt;&gt;', $gallery_page_query->max_num_pages); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The page in question is located at http://www.nickpassaro.com/clientsitedev/NJRI/gallery

If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't use the `archive-` prefix for page templates. This is confusing, not just for humans, but for Wordpress as well. If it is a page template, rather use the correct `page-` prefix

Comment: Another point, do not use gallery as your post type name, it is a reseved name which will cause conflict with core naming conventions

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit lol!

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Will post answer soon :-). Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your naming convention. Look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). The `archive-` prefix is reserved for date and custom post type archive pages. You are using this as prefix to a page template

This is not only confusing to humans, but to Wordpress as well. For page templates you should be using the `page-` prefix. Just a note, as from version 3.4 you don't need the `page-` prefix anymore for page templates :-)